# Web view : webpage is not available

Tags: android

I am working in android. I want to show webpage using webview. But i want to display page in different manner, so i tried to get HTML of that webpage first, then i tried to show that HTML code as web page.

This is my main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
```

This is Activity code:-

```
  public class MyWebViewActivity extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    String resString = "<html><body><h1>Hello, Quippelin...</h1></body></html>";
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://google.com"); 

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); 

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)

            sb.append(line + "\n");

        resString = sb.toString(); 

        is.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    mWebView.loadData(resString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

But whenever I run this application this error is occurred:-
[image]

Please suggest me what mistake i have done. I really need help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally, I got the answer. But this answer might not be a solution either. This is a bug in SDK, refer the link here
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4401.
I confirmed this with my own apps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com ");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Nitesh sir i am very familiar with whatever you describe. Please think about my question. I want to this thing using another way, and that is first step of my application. Means i want to parse HTML of webpage.